# Total Absent and Joined time of each user present in different txt files

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, dictionary

This question is extention of [@user:bone007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66927946/print-the-name-who-has-absent-twice) question which is closed by community due to guidline problem. I tried it some logic but I didn't get any clue for that, here is some point to solve the problem.

I have various attendance files. Property of files are:

1. Format is `.txt`.
2. Per file it contain equal number of people.
3. Per file data is stored `newline` separated.
4. File are as `[file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt . . . .`

**Look at sample :**

```
file1.txt                      |           file2.txt
                               |
abc|absent                     |           abc|absent
                               |
bcd|joined                     |           bcd|joined 
                               |
cde|joined                     |           cde|joined
```

**Requirement :**

1. I want o/p give total `joined-time` of each member.

**Logic i applied is here:**

```
l = []
with open("file1.txt", 'r') as f:
    for i,j in enumerate(f):
        if i%2 != 0:
            continue
        l.append({j.strip('\n').split('|')[0] : j.strip('\n').split('|')[1]})

print(l)
```

But problem with this logic is that this hold for single file , how to extend it for more than one file

Comment: There is nothing about time in those files.  Please show us an example of what the output would look like for the files in your sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For example you have this workspace shown in this file :**

[image]

I divide my code into sub-section :

**Filter `txt file` in given workspace**

```
import os             
all_files = os.listdir("./")
txt_files = list(filter(lambda x: x[-4:] == '.txt', all_files))
```

**Iterate from each file and create a `map of each user` with the help of `dict`**

```
l = []
for file in txt_files:
    with open(rf"{file}", 'r') as f:
        l1 = {}
        for i,j in enumerate(f):
            if i%2 != 0:
                continue
            l1[j.strip('\n').split('|')[0]] = j.strip('\n').split('|')[1]
        l.append(l1)
```

**Finally add similar name value and store into `result dict`**

```
ind = ['absent', 'joined']
result = {'abc': 0, 'bcd': 0, 'cde':0}

for i in l:
    item = i.keys()
    for j in item:
        result[j] += ind.index(i[j])

print(result)
```

**Ouptut : In dict format**

```
{'abc': 0, 'bcd': 2, 'cde': 2}
```

### For Short Logic go with this:

```
import os             
all_files = os.listdir("./")
txt_files = list(filter(lambda x: x[-4:] == '.txt', all_files)) 

l = []
ind = ['absent', 'joined']
result = {'abc': 0, 'bcd': 0, 'cde':0}


for file in txt_files:
    with open(rf"{file}", 'r') as f:
        l1 = {}
        for i,j in enumerate(f):
            if i%2 != 0:
                continue
            l1[j.strip('\n').split('|')[0]] = j.strip('\n').split('|')[1]
        l.append(l1)
    
    for i in l:
        item = i.keys()
        for j in item:
            result[j] += ind.index(i[j])
    l.pop()

print(result)
```

**Ouptut : In dict format**

```
{'abc': 0, 'bcd': 2, 'cde': 2}
```